# Coq simple implies proof

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I am trying to prove the following trivial cancellation theorem for natural numbers:

```
forall i, j, k in nat . ((i+j) = (i+k)) -> (j = k)
```

Here is what I wrote in `Coq`:

```
Theorem cancel : forall (i j k : nat),
  ((add i j) = (add i k)) -> (j = k).
Proof.
intros i j k.
induction i.
simpl.
```

After which `Coq` tries to prove the basis of the induction which is trivial:

```
j = k -> j = k
```

Almost all `Coq` tutorials start with proving `A -> A`, but when I try to use such proofs I get stuck. For example, I'm using:

```
Theorem my_first_proof : (forall A : Prop, A -> A).
Proof.
  intros A.
  intros proof_of_A.
  exact proof_of_A.
Qed.
```

And then when I try to:

```
rewrite -> my_first_proof
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find a relation to rewrite.
```

Any help is very much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right tactic in this case is `apply`.

```
apply my_first_proof.
```

`rewrite` is used to replace one subterm of the goal with another, usually with a lemma showing that these subterms are equal or equivalent in some sense. `my_first_proof` is not an equality proof.